# How to organize Windows and Android builds of my C++ game?

Tags: c++, android, windows, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I would like to develop a Windows build of my Android game for testing and demo purposes. Most of my code is C++, using OpenGL to render, with a thin Android/Java layer that forwards touch events and loads resources.

My first thought was to make a Visual Studio project for my Windows version, as I'm familiar with it and the debugger is excellent.

Can I get similar C++ debugging functionality with Eclipse & CDT? It seems tidier to have all versions working from the same IDE, and it would be nice to become less dependant on proprietary software. Would I be able to add a Windows build configuration in CDT, switch over, and have the IDE launch & debug my Windows version instead? Or would I be entering a world of pain setting this up?

Are there any other approaches I haven't considered? All advice welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDT is a perfectly good Windows development environment.  Just make sure that you have installed the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924).

If the concern is that Visual Studio puts a lot of the Windows-specific code in place for you, you might consider starting a new project in it.  I'd avoid MFC.  Just create a new Win32 project.  Then, you could take that code and use it as the basis for your Eclipse project, folding in the platform-independent code from your original Android game.

Comment: I decided I should give CDT a chance. After a bit of messing about, I have a fairly simple setup. I added a "Windows" build configuration, set to use the MinGW toolchain and CDT internal builder. I "exclude from build" all the Android-specific source files, and added a "main.cpp" that isn't seen by Android.mk. After manually setting the path to gdb (not found automatically with the rest of MinGW for some reason), it all works quite well!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily come up with a cross-IDE solution using makefiles. I guess [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) could help you here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out [MPC](http://www.ociweb.com/products/MPC). It can generate VS solutions or Eclipse CDT projects(and some more). I've been using it at my previous job and it's really neat once you get the hang of it(which shouldn't be very hard). I'm not sure how well does it work in a 
cross-compilation environment, as we were using it to build our project on PC for Linux/Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you shouldn't be able to use Eclipse on WIndows as well.

As far as I know though (I haven't used Eclipse for C++ that much), Visual Studio still has the best debugger. (it can also be a good code health check to compile it with more than one compiler). So there may be reasons to go with VS as well.

If you do decide to go with VS for the Windows version, you may want to look into CMake for managing the build system, since it can generate Visual Studio solutions as well as makefiles and pretty much anything else you may need to build.